# Associate an outlook calendar with another timezone

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I work with some people across different parts of the country and was hoping if I can have their outlook calendars reflect this.

Currently if I display calendars side by side then it shows that persons calendar in their timezone, but does not match the time with mine. If I do not know that the person is in another timezone it makes for difficulty scheduling things.

[image: Example]

In this image the calendar on the right is actually 1 hour behind the calendar on the left, but it is displayed as if they are equal here. Is there a way I can have the calendar on the right be 1 hour behind or tag it as another timezone?

I am using Outlook 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just works automatically in Outlook if both parties have their Time Zone (TZ) and Daylight Savings Time (DST) set correctly:

[image: Calendar screen shot]

The grey areas in above screen shot are outside of their office hours and the white areas are inside.

Maybe the particular person you're having trouble with lives in the Central TZ but works Eastern TZ hours and advanced their clock manually or removed DST instead of changing their TZ as what you're describing is not the normal behaviour. Contact them directly and let them know they can adapt their working hours in Outlook instead of messing around with their clock settings.

Comment: This person does have their clock set to be Central TZ. This looks like you are using a newer version of outlook as well which may be true in your case. I updated my question to clarify I am using Outlook 2010.

Comment: Using 2016 right now, but that worked under 2010 as well.  Have you both activated DST? (If one doesn't, you'll get one hour off)

Comment: Yup we each have it, but even still I have this issue with everyone in CT and so do my colleagues.

Comment: You on-line now?  If yes, see me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Comment: Yes I will head there now

Comment: Awarding you the bounty for providing a solid answer and being the only one to respond

Comment: @Pythonic: Thanks.  I've been extremely busy lately so this was a nice surprise coming back!  *:-)* Favour returned!  Q upvoated!